# Apply OTA Update for Android 4.3 to AT&T SGS3 i747

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, 4.3-jelly-bean, att

My Galaxy S3 (i747) has just informed me that there is an OTA update available from AT&T. I have stock Android 4.1.1 on there right now, but I have the device rooted with Clockwork 5.x.

When I attempted to apply the OTA update, the phone (at first) looked like it was going to apply it, but then Clockwork opened with the error: `Failed to verify whole-file signature` (along with some other messages) and when I rebooted, Android said something like "The update was interrupted."

So, here's my question, I guess: Is there something I can do with Clockwork 5.x where it can apply the OTA update for me **-or-** do I need to:

1. Flash stock AT&T recovery (Will this remove root? Does that even matter?)
2. Apply the update in the "official" way
3. Re-download and re-apply Clockwork to re-root the device

If I follow either of these steps, all of my data will be preserved during the upgrade, correct?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you'll lose root (and need to re-root) with this update no matter what. And I believe you'd need to flash the stock recovery in order to run the OTA update. But you'll be able to flash CWM back on and re-root afterward.

Comment: Any idea where I can find a copy of stock recovery, and/or instructions on how to do that? Would I just use ODIN to apply that? It's been awhile since I've messed around with flashing anything on my phone.

Comment: Actually, looking at http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-unroot/how-to-unroot-att-galaxy-s3-sgh-i747/ makes me think you might not be able to just get the bootloader. But I'm possibly wrong about this!